# Why is paint not being called?

Tags: java, paint

I've created a class with three methods. I originally started with slightly different coding, and have changed it after looking at several videos and questions until I ended up with this. For some reason, the square I am trying to make simply will not appear on my screen. Please make any suggestions you have. I started relatively recently, which I'm sure is obvious. Please excuse any conventional errors I have made. As a side note, I figured out that the problem is that the method "paint" isn't being called. As I'm new I have no idea how to call it after trying a few different ways. If you have any clarifying questions about my code please ask. Thanks!

```
public class TheGame extends JPanel {

public void screen() {
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setTitle("Grid Game");
    f.setResizable(false);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setBounds(250, 250, 500, 500);
    f.add(this);
    f.setVisible(true);
}

public void paint(Graphics2D g) {
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fillRect(50, 50, 200, 200);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    TheGame game = new TheGame();
    game.screen();
}
```

Comment: There is no `paint(Graphics2D)` method in `JPanel`, so that method is not an override, i.e. it is never called. You would know this if you added the `@Override` annotation. It is what that annotation is for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `override` the `paintComponent()` method:

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fillRect(50, 50, 200, 200);
}
```